# jQuery Colorbox doesn't work with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, lightbox, colorbox

I'm using AJAX to load content from single post(Wordpress). On single page I have image with jQuery Colorbox (https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-colorbox/). After adding the AJAX Colorbox stopped working.

AJAX:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

        var hoverOrClick = function() {

            var post_url = $(this).attr("href");

            $("#hide-ccontent").load(post_url);
            return false;
        }

        $("#ccontent a").click(hoverOrClick).hover(hoverOrClick);   
});
```

Script downloaded from: http://www.designlunatic.com/2011/06/dynamically-load-wordpress-posts-with-jquery/

I tried to put in single code like this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

                $("a#lightbox").colorbox();
            });
</script>
```

Sometimes it works, but it doesn't completely resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Colorbox script is default located in the header. In my case it was necessary to change location to the footer(you can do it in plugin menu). Works fine now.

Single.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("a#lightbox").colorbox();
});
```